# Clearing a PHP Search Input Form on Click & after Idle

Tags: php, forms

Is there a way in PHP to have an input field in a search form box show up, and then, when the user clicks on the search box, then the text clears for them to enter their search term?

Or, let's say if they click on the search box and don't add anything. Is there a way to have the input field then revert back to the default text?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div id="searchform" class="noprint">
<?php
  echo form_open('recipe/search', array('class' => 'form'));
  echo form_input(array('name' =>'query','onfocus' => "this.value = '';", 'value' => 'Recipe Search'));
  echo form_submit('submit', 'Search', 'class="button"');
  echo form_close();
 ?>
</div>
```

Comment: In PHP, no. PHP runs on the server, not the client. You can do this using Javascript pretty easily.